# How do I set expression for a parmater in sql server reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hi All,

How do i set expression for a parameter in sql server reporting services r2?

Is it even possible?

The expression button is not even there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this through the web application, In the web application I use the report-viewer control to gain accesses to the parameters.
With the parameters at hand I have complete control on what should be displayed (exression 
It's a workaround but it works.

Answer (score 1):

At design time in the parameters dialogue box just type in the expression for the default value if the button isn't there.

```
= Now()
```

If you mean at runtime, then no you can't.

Comment: I tried =NOW() at the parameter prompt and it didn't evaluate the expression and just printed =NOW() as the parameter prompt

Comment: At runtime, you can't do this, as per my last sentence above